# Requirejs, issue in loading the library underscore

Tags: underscore.js, requirejs

I am using the require.version "2.0.0"
And I would like to get the underscore as a local variable:

Here's my code (1).

Why _ is undefined?
How can I get `_` inside the function like a local variable

---

(1)

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "./",
    paths: {
        'underscore': 'vendor/js/underscore-min'
    },
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: 'underscore'
        }
    }
});

require([
    'underscore'
 ], function(_) {
    "use strict";
    console.log(_); // undefined
});
```

Comment: Do you use the AMD fork of Underscore https://github.com/amdjs/underscore ? If not, that could explain your problem

Comment: @nikoshr thanks for your comment.  I am not using the AMD fork of Underscore. anyway there is a way to fix this issue without using the AMD version?

Comment: @nikoshr Anyway if you look this [article](http://tbranyen.com/post/amdrequirejs-shim-plugin-for-loading-incompatible-javascript)  it seems that shim has been introduced to fix the not AMD plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, just replace `exports: 'underscore'` by `exports: '_'`.
This tells require to attach to `_` the module. So the reference `window._` will still work.